# jquery ID of previous dynamically added text area

Tags: jquery, forms, text, upload, textarea

I'm attempting to hack a wordpress plugin to gain some extra functionality.

As it stands i've adjusted it so I can add a new textarea with it's own upload box.

I now need a way to get the ID of the new textarea, so I can pass the uploaded file text back to the correct textarea.

this is my code:

**JQUERY:**

```
<script type="text/jquery">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery('#upload_image_button').live("click", function() {
 var tblID = jQuery(this).closest("textarea").attr("id");
 alert(tblID); // returns undefined.


 formfield = jQuery('#upload_image').attr('name');
 tb_show('','media-upload.php?type=image&TB_iframe=true');
 return false;
});
</script>
```

as it stands, this doesn't work. I get "undefined", rather than the ID of the text area as I hoped.

the markup for each DIV that gets added is like this, where * indicates a unique number:

```
<div id="my*Div>
<textarea class="dfrads_textarea" id="dfrads_textarea_*" name="ad_*">
  <!-- my content -->
</textarea>
Upload:
<label for="upload_image"><input type="text" value="" name="upload_image_*" size="36" id="upload_image_*"><input type="button" value="Upload Image" id="upload_image_button_*"><br>Enter an URL or upload an image for the banner.</label>
</div>
```

so if I add 2 extra DIVs, the * would be "2" in this example. (The second DIV).

How can I get the value of the ID of the textarea that is "paired" with the submit button.

thanks ! I have tried .prev and .closest, but presumably am using it wrongly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's not *inside* the `<textarea>` you need to [traverse](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) a bit differently, replace this:

```
jQuery(this).closest("textarea").attr("id");
```

With this:

```
jQuery(this).closest("label").prev("textarea").attr("id");
```

This goes up to the `<label>` then back to the `<textarea>` previous sibling...your selector isn't quite right on the [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) call, at least not for the markup, but if you're getting an alert at all I'll assume it's just not *quite* as posted and is working correctly.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense but still returns "undefined". The original code didnt have `.live` call - it was a .click(), but with just `.click`, the jquery didn't pick up the newly generated html (i think)

Comment: scratch that, works fine, was me being a muppet. What's wrong with the .live() call if you don't mind enlightening me. thanks again

Comment: @calum - The `.live()` call is referencing the ID `upload_image_button` which *should* be changing, so no new buttons should match it...either you're getting duplicate IDs or something else is going on.  I'd be safe and remove the ID, just change the button to having a class and `.live()` bind to that.